# How to authorize and then capture authorized payment in paypal using csharp

Tags: c#, paypal

I am working on paypal API integration in c# with the help of paypal developer's documentation, but they haven't provided documentation for creating authorized payment. How can I create authorized payment and then capture it?

Comment: Work your way through the PayPal documentation: work out which APIs you need to call as a start. Then start working on the first one. Add plenty of logging and when you hit a specific problem as here (with a re-create).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating authorized payment is same as creating regular payment. You just need to change the intent of payment "authorize" instead of "sale".